# angular foreach result adding up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

I'm having an issue with the following code :

```
function getTotalChildAttr2(parent,child) {
           var res = 0;
           for (var i = 0, iMax = 2; i < iMax; i++) {
              angular.forEach(vm.filteredRoutersSummaries[i], function (summary) {
                res += summary[parent][child];
                });
           }
           console.log(vm.filteredRoutersSummaries);
           return res;
       }
```

Basically the problem with this is that res adds up with every vm.filteredRoutersSummaries due to [i], and then returns res, what i would like is that res is returned for every vm.filteredRoutersSummaries.
for exemple (vm.filteredRoutersSummaries is an array, but let's imagine it's just an integer) if i have :

```
vm.filteredRoutersSummaries[0] = 10
vm.filteredRoutersSummaries[1] = 15
```

currently, i would get returned res = 25, well what i want is :
res = 10 with vm.filteredRoutersSummaries[0] and res = 15 with vm.filteredRoutersSummaries[1]. 
( because later i do for exemple :

```
vm.routers[i].value = getTotalChildAttr2('real', 'value');
```

I can make that happen by doing it in two functions (without using a for condition, and simply replace i by 0 in vm.filteredRoutersSummaries in the angular.foreach in the 1st function, and by 1 in the 2nd function. 
I don't really know if that's very clear, if you have any questions please don't mind asking me ! TY !

Comment: I think you need to **pass the index**: `getTotalChildAttr2('real', 'value', i);` and then resolve the answer only for `vm.filteredRoutersSummaries[i]`. Maybe something like: `vm.filteredRoutersSummaries[i].reduce((x,y)=>{return x+y[parent][child]},0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope i understood your problem, but sincerly it is not very clear.

How about:

```
function getTotalChildAttr2(parent, child, index) {
    var res = 0;

    angular.forEach(vm.filteredRoutersSummaries[index], function (summary) {
            res += summary[parent][child];
    });

    console.log(vm.filteredRoutersSummaries);

    return res;
}
```

and then:

```
vm.routers[i].value = getTotalChildAttr2('real', 'value', i);
```

Is it ok for you?

Comment: My Super Hero ! Thanks for taking the time to understanding my explication, yeah i know was not very clear, not english native :p, did not really understand how to explain, Thanks again !